# MYSQL- Help making a query

Tags: mysql

Solved! Thanks for all the help!

How do I fix this query

So the Pet's table's fields are

> Pet_Code,Name,Employee_code,Type,Sex

And the Employees table's fields are

> Employee_code,Last_Name,First_Name,Department

This is what I tried but didn't work:

```
SELECT First_Name,Last_Name 
FROM employees E,pets P 
WHERE P.Employee_code=E.Employee_code AND COUNT(Type='C') > Count(Type='D');
```

Comment: Can you post what you've got so far?

Comment: select First_Name,Last_Name from employees E,pets P where P.Employee_code=E.Employee_code AND COUNT(Type='C') > Count(Type='D'); But it doesn't work :(

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok you can try this:

```
SELECT DISTINCT
 E.Employee_code, E.Last_Name, E.Department,
 (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM pet WHERE Employee_code = E.Employee_code AND Type = 'C') AS cats,
 (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM pet WHERE Employee_code = E.Employee_code AND Type = 'D') AS dogs
FROM employee E
 LEFT JOIN pet P ON E.Employee_code = P.Employee_code
GROUP BY E.Employee_code
HAVING cats > dogs
```

it is like previous one, But more simply

Comment: No need for distinct when you include all the grouping columns in the output nor is the join even necessary when you do the counts in a subquery.

Answer (score 0):

I think you could try this:

```
SELECT 
Employee_code,
Last_Name,
First_Name,
SUM(CASE WHEN Type = 'C' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS CAT,
SUM(CASE WHEN Type = 'D' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS DOG
FROM Employees_TABLE E
JOIN PET_TABLE P ON E.Employee_code = P.Employee_code
GROUP BY Employee_code 
HAVING SUM(CASE WHEN Type = 'C' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) > SUM(CASE WHEN Type = 'D' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END)
```

Comment: Sadly, that gives me a Syntax error, appreciate the help though.

Comment: i've just edited. Could u try this again. I think that should work

Comment: Just tried it again, still gives me a syntax error.

Comment: Little bit modification:
`SELECT 
E.Employee_code,
Last_Name,
First_Name,
SUM(CASE WHEN Type = 'C' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS CAT,
SUM(CASE WHEN Type = 'D' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS DOG
FROM employee E
JOIN pet P ON E.Employee_code = P.Employee_code
GROUP BY Employee_code 
HAVING SUM(CASE WHEN Type = 'C' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) > SUM(CASE WHEN Type = 'D' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END)`

Comment: `SELECT Employee_code,` is ambiguous column, you must determine from any table you will retrieve it

Comment: This is the error: "ERROR 1064 (42000): You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near ') > SUM(CASE WHEN Type = 'D' THEN 1 ELSE 0)' at line 8" Also, according to my TA, there is a way simpler way to solve this without using CASE

Comment: Cool! It works, but is there a way to do it without CASE? Just curious because this is from a list of practice questions for a test next week and we didn't learn CASE

Comment: i think the answer is no

Comment: Also, I just need to show First and Last name, but result data shows CATS AND DOGs as well. How do I remove that?

Comment: SELECT Last_Name,
First_Name
FROM (
SELECT 
Employee_code,
Last_Name,
First_Name,
SUM(CASE WHEN Type = 'C' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS CAT,
SUM(CASE WHEN Type = 'D' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS DOG
FROM Employees_TABLE E
JOIN PET_TABLE P ON E.Employee_code = P.Employee_code
GROUP BY Employee_code 
HAVING SUM(CASE WHEN Type = 'C' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) > SUM(CASE WHEN Type = 'D' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END))

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you can try with this:

```
SELECT e.First_Name, e.Last_Name
FROM employees e INNER JOIN pets p ON e.Employee_code = p.Employee_code
WHERE 
    (SELECT COUNT(*) 
     FROM pets p1
     WHERE p1.Type = 'C' AND p.Employee_code = p1.Employee_code) > 
    (SELECT COUNT(*)
     FROM pets p1
     WHERE p1.Type = 'D' AND p.Employee_code = p1.Employee_code)
GROUP BY e.Employee_code;
```

It might not be an optimal solution, but should do the job.

Answer (score 0):

```
select min(e.First_Name), min(e.Last_Name)
from emp e left outer join pets p
    on p.Employee_Code = e.Employee_Code
group by e.Employee_Code
having
    count(case when Type = 'C' then 1 end) >
    count(case when Type = 'D' then 1 end)
```